# Jquery Binding a context menu to dynamic element id

Tags: javascript, dynamic, contextmenu, bind

Basic story, I've got a system that handles each div id dynamically. I decided to take over the context menu with one of my own, and it works, so long as the id of the element is hardcoded. I've been trying to write a function that takes the element name from a list of arrays, and its throwing errors left an right.

```
function menuclick()
{
alert("Menuclick Called");
var limen= ["armenu", "ormenu", "prmenu", "apmenu", "auxmenu", "itmenu", "sysmenu"];
var menues= Array();
var men1 = "menu$pf1$topmen$topmen$menul$menuli$";
for (idx=0;idx<6;idx++){
    menues[idx] = "#"+men1+limen[idx];
    $(menues[idx]).bind("contextmenu", this.id, function(e) {
        $('#example-menu').css({
            top: e.pageY+'px',
            left: e.pageX+'px'
        }).show();
return false;
});
    alert(menues[idx]);
}
return;
}
```

The $(menues[idx]).bind is whats causing the issue, mainly the menues[idx]. but i cant figure out why. any suggestions?

EDIT ** forgot to mention, the error firebug shows is:

> "uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: $pf1$topmen$topmen$menul$menuli$armenu"

EDIT** this uses php to get the div id's from a database.

Answer (score 0):

ohhh `.NET` and its silly conventions.  You are trying to reference a "name" and not an "id".  Your menu markup should look something like this:

```
<div name="menu$pf1$topmen$topmen$menul$menuli$armenu" id="menu_pf1_topmen_topmen_menul_menuli_armenu"> ... </div>
```

So, that being said you have two options.

- 1) Change your dolar signs to underscores (recommended)

`var men1 = "menu_pf1_topmen_topmen_menul_menuli_";`

- 2) Change the following line of code:

`menues[idx] = "#"+men1+limen[idx];`

to this:

`menues[idx] = "[name='" + men1 + limen[idx] + "']";`

Comment: Sorry for making assumptions.  the naming convention you posted is used heavily by .NET and webforms.  The problem with your code is that dollar signs are not allowed in IDs.  IDs must begin with a letter and contain letters, numbers, underscores, hyphens, and periods.

Comment: its ok, the way I coded it is a little... unconventional. if anyone has an idea why this is happening please put some info in.

Comment: Do you have any control over the generated content?  While you are generating ids with dollar signs, Javascript is always going to choke because the dollar sign is not valid in an ID.

Comment: the div is actually placed by php. the $ is a php variable that contains the actual div name (retrieved from a database). so "$div1" would display as #menu

Comment: Basically there are 2 different parts of the code: 1) the code in the PHP file, and 2) the rendered output HTML.  If you can't prevent the dollar signs from ending up in the rendered HTML, then your problem is not going to go away and JavaScript will always have problems.  Can you describe the framework you are using.  PHP doesn't do this by default.

Comment: The framework is a custom framework built by my company to be a mysql based script. Every variable, css element, html element, etc has been stored in the database, and the php calls this database when painting the page.

Comment: Well you need to tell your architect he is an [some word for idiot here] and he needs to change his framework so that it outputs valid HTML.  Otherwise, your problem cannot be solved.